# Using a for loop to print keys and/or values in a dictionary for python. Looking for logical thinking explanation thanks :D

Tags: python, python-3.x

My problem is understanding why these certain lines of code do what they do. Basically why it works logically. I am using PyCharm python 3 I think.

```
house_Number = {
    "Luca": 1, "David": 2, "Alex": 3, "Kaden": 4, "Kian": 5
}

for item in house_Number:
    print(house_Number[item])  # Why does this print the values tied with the key?
    print(item)  # Why does this print the key?
```

This is my first question so sorry I don't know how to format the code to make it look nice. My question is why when you use the for loop to print the dictionary key or value the syntax to print the key is to print every item? And what does it even mean to print(house_Number[item]).

They both work to print key or value but I really want to know a logical answer as to why it works this way. Thanks :D

I'm not working on any projects just starting to learn off of codeacademey.

Comment: I think you should continue your tutorial a bit more re: accessing values in a dictionary by key. If the tutorial doesn't answer the questions then there is an issue. Lots of things won't make sense, however the tutorial structures itself, so hopefully they can answer it by the time you complete the course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, iteration over a dictionary (`for item in dict`) is defined as iteration over that dictionary's *keys*. This is simply how the language was designed -- other languages and collection classes do it differently, iterating, for example, over key-value tuples, templated `Pair<X,Y>` objects, or what have you.

`house_Number[item]` accesses the value in `house_Number` referenced by the key `item`. `[...]` is the syntax for *indexing* in Python (and most other languages); `an_array[2]` gives the third element of `an_array` and `house_Number[item]` gives the value corresponding to the key `item` in the dictionary `house_Number`.

Just a side note: Python [naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) would dictate `house_number`, not `house_Number`. Capital letters are generally only used in `CamelCasedClassNames` and `CONSTANTS`.

Comment: So just to clarify, for item.... item refers to the key of the dictionary?

Comment: @trevor trinh: yes

Answer (score 1):

In python values inside a dictionary object are accessed using dictionay_name['KEY'] 
In your case you are iterating over the keys of dictionary
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
for item in dic:
    print(item)  # key
    print(dic[item])  # value
```

Dictionaries are basically containers containing some items (keys) which are stored by hashing method. These keys just map to the values (dic[key]).
Like in `set`, if you traverse using `for` loop, you get the keys from it (in random order since they are hashed). Similarly, dictionaries are just `sets` with a value associated with it. it makes more sense to iterate the keys as in `sets` (too in random order).

Answer (score 0):

Read more about dicionaries here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries and hopefully that will answer your question.  Specifically, look at the `.items()` method of the dictionary object.

Answer (score 0):

When you type for item in `house_Number`, you don’t specify whether `item` is the key or value of `house_Number`. Then python just thinks that you meant the key of `house_Number`.

So when you do the function `print(house_Number[item])`, you’re printing the value because your taking the key and finding the value. In other words, you taking each key once, and finding their values, which are `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`

The `print(item)` is just to print the item, which are the keys, `"Luca", "David", "Alex", "Kaden", "Kian"`

Because the `print(house_Number[item])` and `print(item)` alternating, you get the keys and values alternating, each on a new line.